# Is prism using legacy code?

Tags: wpf, prism

We are using prism for developing WPF applications. The newest(4.1) version supports only windows 7 and windows server 2008 as per the following link

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=28950

This begs a question. As far as I know specific operating system support is only required for assemblies with legacy code. If the assembly is completely written in .NET it just need the .NET frame work support as this itself is a "virtual machine".

If this is true is prism contains legacy code?

Answer (score 2):

The Prism 4.1 Deveoper's Guide provided [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx) says the following:

This guidance was designed to run on the Microsoft Windows 7, Windows Vista, or Windows Server 2008 operating system. **This version has been smoke tested on Windows XP Professional and Windows Server 2003, but it has not been exhaustively tested**. WPF applications built using this guidance require the .NET Framework 4.0 and Silverlight applications require Silverlight 5.

All this means is that they haven't tested it on XP, but you needed XP SP 3 and above for the last release (the minimum for .NET 4.0), so my **guess** is it will likely work for new projects.

No need to panic.

Comment: Actually, my question was about why it is specifying OS requirement instead of framework requirement which is answered by Joe White as you can see the comment section of Phil's answer. He didn't put it as an actual answer for me to mark it.

Comment: @Jimmy What they are saying is that they have exhaustively tested it on Win7, Vista, and 2008, but not XP Pro or 2003.  Yes, they said it is an OS requirement, but in this case the download page is less reliable than the Developer page, imho.  BTW, I added that Prism 4 required > XP SP3, but the reason for that was a .NET requirement, which was so **because** of the OS.  It's 6 of one and 1/2 dozen of the other.

Comment: @Jimmy Also, Joe/Phil is saying he guesses that the reason they didn't include the older OS's is because of some low level OS requirement.  Indeed, this is not the case.  They just haven't tested it.  So technically, Joe/Phil was wrong, it is not because of an OS dependency.

Comment: @Bahri-It is just like this.  I have an application and I can say this application will work on Windows XP. My application runs on Windows XP and if I have to specify anything below the OS layer that complicates things. So .NET is also a virtual machine which I thought is completely self contained.  Actually that is not the case as Joe pointed out. That is probably why they need to test prism on different OS. That "why" was my question.